# Changing recurrent connections and equations of RNN/LSTM in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

According to the [tensorflow documantaion](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/rnn_cells_for_use_with_tensorflow_s_core_rnn_methods#BasicLSTMCell), the RNN in Tensorflow supports the following equation:

```
activation(W * input + U * state + B)
```

Now, what would be the best practice to implemnet RNN as follow:

```
activation(W_1 * input_1 + W_2 * input_2 + U * state + B)
```

By the best practice, I mean the fast and efficient way to implement RNN/LSTM with slightly different equations: edit tf.nn.rnn_cell such that it can support this or? [For this example, assume we can't concat input_1 and input_2 since they have different dimensions]

In general, if we want to change a bit the equations of LSTM/RNN (i.e. add new inputs, new recurrent connections, and etc), where we should start in TF? any suggestions? Which files should be changed? A pointer to any tutorial or code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy to do using Tensorflow's RNN cell library. Each RNN cell type is implemented a subclass of RNNCell; you can easily add your own new subclass. Take a look at the code that defines some of the common RNN cells:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So by implementing a new RNNCell, is it required to re-implement all other classes in rnn.py such as dynamic_rnn, etc?

Comment: `dynamic_rnn` is parametric in the cell type. You can pass it your own custom RNN cell type and things should work.

Comment: hey I know that this is an old question but I have the same problem and the link is dead, how can I find this information?